# jquery file upload in rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

when i click on start upload button it is redirecting to http://jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/ but i could not seen whether my image has uploaded or not.

Comment: Have you done any researched before you posted?

Comment: I meant have you coded anything yet? Done some work? We are here to help you with a problem that you at least put some effort into. Not do all the work for you. If you don't know how to code learn [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) or hire someone.

Answer (score 1):

you can look at [jquery fileupload rails](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails)

Install the gem by adding this to your Gemfile `gem "jquery-fileupload-rails"`

now in this path **app/assets/application.js** add `//= require jquery-fileupload` this will add all the js files need

for the css **app/assets/stylesheets/application.css** add

```
*= require jquery.fileupload
*= require jquery.fileupload-ui
```

you can follow the [jQuery-File-Upload /wiki/ Basic-plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin) on how to set up or watch the [railscasts.com on jquery file upload](http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload)

This is your basic upload form

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="server/php/" multiple>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

hope that this helps.